# Real function with real variable

Tags: calculus, functions

I am supposed to solve this problem, but I don't really know how to deal with it... Any help would be appreciated!

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function that satisfies $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0.$$ Prove that, provided $n$ is even, there exists  a real number $z$ such that $$f(z)+z^n\leq f(x)+x^n,$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$h(t) =f(t) +t^n $$ the function is continious and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty } h(x) =+\infty$ hence $h$ attains its global minimum at some $z\in\mathbb{R}$ thus $$\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}} h(z)\leqslant h(x)$$